# Source Maps with Gulp, Browserify, Babel, ES6, and React

Tags: gulp, browserify, babeljs, source-maps

I am using Gulp with Browserify, and Babelify for ES6 and JSX-React transpiling. Despite numerous examples online, I can't figure out how to generate source-maps that point to the original *pre-transpiled ES6/JSX files*.

Here is my current gulp browserify task, [which is based on this example](https://gist.github.com/danharper/3ca2273125f500429945):

```
gulp.task('browserify', function() {
  browserify({ entries: './src/js/main.jsx', extensions: ['.jsx'], debug: true })
    .transform(babelify, {presets: ["es2015", "react"]})
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('main.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});
```

All this does is create a `main.js.map` file that seems to have the exact same content as the bundled `main.js` file. In Chrome it looks like this:

[image]

But I want to debug the original source `.jsx` and `.js` (with ES6 syntax) files. They look like this in my IDE:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Like many before me, I switched to WebPack and got it working immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Add sourcemaps:true to babelify options

```
{presets: ["es2015", "react"],sourcemaps:true}
```

Comment: Thanks, I want to say I tried this and it made no difference, but I've since switched to WebPack which was *much* easier to get working, so unfortunately I can't verify this answer right now.

Answer (score 0):

I simply had to change the settings in `webpack.config.js`

```
{ 
    devtool: 'source-map', // Or some other option that generates the original source as seen from https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
    ...
}
```

You don't have to modify the `sourceMap` query param in Babel Loader because it is inferred from the `devtool` option of the Webpack config.